# How to display the value of a variable from an model?

Tags: flutter, dart

I make an `API` request and get data. I have created models in which the received values are stored. I'm using the `gallery` variable to store a list of photo links. Tell me, how can I access an element from this list of the `gallery` variable in order to display a photo by link?

**model**

```
class User {
  final int id;
  final List<PhotoModel>? gallery;

  User({
    required this.id,
    this.gallery,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<PhotoModel> ph = [];
    json['gallery'].forEach((v) {
      ph.add(PhotoModel.fromJson(v));
    });

    return User(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      gallery: ph,
    );
  }
}
```

**model2**

```
class PhotoModel {
  final String url;

  PhotoModel({required this.url});

  factory PhotoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PhotoModel(
      url: json['url'],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what I get

[image]

Comment: Did you try widget.state.user!.gallery.join(" ");

Answer (score 1):

You print out `user.gallary` which is a list of `PhotoModel` instances. So your output makes sense it seems so that your gallery contains one `PhotoModel`.

If you want a specific output for each `PhotoModel` you have several options:

1. Override the `toString()` in the `PhotoModel` class and return the `url`
2. Change your `print` statement so it directly prints the url instead of the object itself.  `print(widget.state.user!.gallery.map((p) => p.url));`

Another alternative is to add an `toJson()` method to your class which works the other way around like `fromJson()` and returns a map. If you call this method and print the map every attribute of the model will be visible.